# как сделать landing с SSR отдельно от CSR(SPA)?

Tags: seo, spa, ssr

У меня есть SPA приложение на React/Redux, я знаю что для SSR можно использовать NEXT.JS или еще что-то но не хочу тратить время, да и нужды в этом нет. Мне необходимо сделать только одну страницу (главный landing) SSR. Просто версту без React, или React но SSR. Это необходимо для SEO оптимизации. Как это можно сделать? Что бы поиск индексировал главный landing, который с SSR, и что бы потом там была кнопка типа: "login" или еще что-то, и она уже вела на страницу login'а самого SPA приложения без SSR. Мне необходим SSR только на главной странице.

Answer (score 0):

Да просто проверь сервак или нет

```js
if(!window) {
   return <ServerContent/>
} else {
   return <ClientContent/>
}
```

если window Не прокатит попробуй process.browser